# Bind specific key name to a property for URL encoded POST data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

Let me have this Razor page

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<form method="post">
    <input class="form-control" name="some-parameter-name"/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And this code behind

```cs
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public class PostParameters
    {
        [WhatIsThisAttribute("some-parameter-name")]
        public string SomeParameterName { get; set; }
    }
    [BindProperty] public PostParameters Parameters { get; set; }
    public void OnGet() {} 
    public void OnPost() {}
}
```

After you press "Submit" data is posted using simple `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` MIME type. I would like to bind data associated with the key `some-parameter-name` to the property `SomeParameterName`. Is there some attribute for such a conversion? Or is there any other way to do it? It will obviously work if I rename the key to `SomeParameterName` but I would like to keep it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BindProperty` to bind the name `some-parameter-name` like this `[BindProperty(Name ="some-parameter-name")]`. Here is a demo worked:

cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public class PostParameters
    {
        [BindProperty(Name = "some-parameter-name")]
        public string SomeParameterName { get; set; }
    }
    [BindProperty] public PostParameters Parameters { get; set; }
    public ActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return Page();
    }
    public void OnPost()
    {
        var spName = Parameters.SomeParameterName;
    }
}
```

result:
[image]